# How to select one href tag without nested tag

Tags: php, html

**html part**

```
<div class="headlines">
  <a href="link.php"> </a>

  <a href="link.php"> </a>
 
   <img src="">

</div>

<div class="headlines">
  <a href="link.php"> </a>

  <a href="link.php"> </a>
 
   <img src="">

</div>
```

**php part**

```
    require_once "xpath.php";
    
    $startUrl ="index.php";
    
    $xpath = new XPATH($startUrl);
    
    $linkHref = $xpath->query("//div[@class='headlines']/a/@href");
    $imageSrc = $xpath->query("//div[@class='headline']//img/@src");
    
     $data = array();

     for($x=0; $x<$imageSrc->length; $x++){
          $data[$x]['imageSrclink'] = $imageSrc->item($x)->nodeValue;
          $data[$x]['dataLinks'] = $linkHref->item($x)->nodeValue; 
        
 }

 echo "<pre>";

 print_r($data);
```

I am trying to use the length for the img tag to match the href tag but the href tag is not equal to the img tag. what I mean is that, I want to have two href tag instead of four.

Comment: Is this your code? Can you add some ID? Which tag you wanna get? Just the first?

Comment: Sorry! I made some changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first occurrence of each "a" tag (a[1]) in each "div" tag:

```
$linkHref = $xpath->query("//div[@class='headlines']/a[1]/@href");
```